# What's the fastest way to create 1GB file filled with zeros in C/C++?

Tags: c++, windows, file-io

I need to create a huge binary file filled with zeros in Windows OS. Its size is given. What's the most efficient way to do it in C/C++?

Comment: Which operating system do you use?

Comment: which os are you on? Are you looking for a platform independent way of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try calling `truncate(2)`:

```
truncate("/my/file", my_size);
```

For more information,

```
man 2 truncate
```

> The truncate() and ftruncate() functions cause the regular file named by path or referenced by fd to be truncated to a size of precisely length bytes.
>
> If the file previously was larger than this size, the extra data is lost.  If the file previously was shorter, it is extended, and the extended part reads as null bytes ('\0').

If you are looking for the Windows native function, take a look at [SetEndOfFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which does much the same thing.

Comment: This should work on any POSIX-2001 compliant system, and probably some that aren't.  It at least exists on Mac, Unix, Linux.  Not sure about Windows.

Comment: AFAIK, truncate creates a sparse file. If he needs to write over those zeroes eventually, it will be anything but fast.

Answer (score 6):

If the file really need to be all zeroes, then there is no other way than to write all of the data. I would probably do it using a buffer of the same size as the drive block-size, and write it in a loop until you written to the size you want.

If the file can contain "holes" where the data is undefined (what's on the disk already really) you can seek to the specified size and write a single byte. Holes like that will actually be read as zeros.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone is wondering how I resolved my issue here:

```
void CreateBlankFile(LPSTR str, long lsize) {
    DWORD dwErr;
    HANDLE file = CreateFile(str, 
                             GENERIC_WRITE,
                             FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                             NULL,
                             CREATE_ALWAYS,
                             FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                             NULL);
    dwErr = GetLastError();
    if (dwErr > 0) {
        //some error message should be here
        return;
    }
    SetFilePointer(file, lsize, 0, FILE_BEGIN);
    SetEndOfFile(file);
    CloseHandle(file);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"Fastest" is platform-dependent. On unix, use open and write system-calls; be sure to call write with a large buffer (~ 1MB).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what your are looking for, `SPARSE` file. These type of files are generally created by file-sharing programs...

http://www.flexhex.com/docs/articles/sparse-files.phtml